# Mac OS 9 Browsers

Tags: browser, virus, web, mac-os-classic

I have a client who doesn't want to upgrade to OS X because of licenses, and needing to update software etc.

The last time I did some browsing on his computer, using a very old version of Internet Explorer (I think), a whole bunch of porn got downloaded onto the desktop, and the browser locked up (I think this was from some free driver site).

What could you recommend?

Is there a secure browser for Mac OS 9?

Is there a way to automatically take all the Mac OS 9 software (e.g Quark) to OS X?

Answer (score 2):

Well there's really no such thing as a secure browser, some are just more secure than others and Mac IE 5 (the version you have) is particularly insecure. You could search around for other OS 9 browsers but they're unlikely to be noticably more secure than what you have, things have moved on a lot in the last **NINE** years since OSX has been out.

As for automatically updating, no there's not, simply because you'd need to buy the newer versions of all the code.

That said I think that if your client cares about their business they should invest in new hardware and software as what they have now is unsupportably-old and likely to be a major risk to their business.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the only two browsers for Mac OS 9 still in (more or less) active development are [iCab](http://www.icab.de/) and [Classilla](http://www.floodgap.com/software/classilla/). Both are no match for modern browser like Firefox or IE with respect to Javascript/CSS support and stability, but probably a lot better than IE 5.

That said, I agree with Chopper3: Do explain to them that they will have to upgrade sooner or later, and explain the problems they are incurring by not doing so.

Answer (score 1):

While it was possible to move from OS 9 to OS X without losing all your programs (with Classic), Classic was removed from the operating system starting with Mac OS X Leopard. At this date and time they've waited too long without needing to upgrade if they purchase new hardware. They can try and get used hardware and run Mac OS X 10.4 with Classic but they'll need to upgrade their versions sooner than later.